# Mapping dict of dict values to create new result

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dataframe, dictionary

I am working on dict of dict dataset :

```
data = {'box_1': {'total_packets': 20,
  'packet_loss': 0.32,
  'network_loss': 0.11,
  'full_packets': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  'full_network': [0.77118516, 0.15721157, 0.99284172, 0.64352685, 0.43893093,
         0.90650645, 0.31344131, 0.98757972, 0.67239033, 0.45789615,
         0.14901635, 0.86344737, 0.46589434, 0.66976324, 0.19622047,
         0.38090317, 0.76307877, 0.26002821, 0.20494155, 0.84978815],
  'true_packets': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]},
 'box_2': {'total_packets': 20,
  'packet_loss': 0.12,
  'network_loss': 0.11,
  'full_packets': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
  'full_network': [0.05200178, 0.27056008, 0.10674939, 0.78031958, 0.18292721,
         0.52281292, 0.94423851, 0.07988127, 0.6556706 , 0.82108989,
         0.13918205, 0.23900761, 0.45053918, 0.80958751, 0.21787875,
         0.38729694, 0.64058867, 0.35293909, 0.3345066 , 0.52221203],
  'true_packets': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]},
 'box_3': {'total_packets': 20,
  'packet_loss': 0.62,
  'network_loss': 0.11,
  'full_packets': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
  'full_network': [0.65296846, 0.79348183, 0.30903056, 0.44789374, 0.63215569,
         0.2749674 , 0.21142709, 0.77792007, 0.70627136, 0.44096512,
         0.1406084 , 0.92678541, 0.36632565, 0.24307549, 0.22864354,
         0.91516214, 0.7331007 , 0.66654516, 0.32463232, 0.35959552],
  'true_packets': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]}}
```

> Expected output :

```
     packets    box  true_value
0   0.771185  box_1           0
1   0.793482  box_3           1
2   0.309031  box_3           0
3   0.447894  box_3           1
4   0.632156  box_3           0
5   0.274967  box_3           0
6   0.211427  box_3           0
7   0.777920  box_3           1
8   0.672390  box_1           1
9   0.440965  box_3           1
10  0.140608  box_3           0
11  0.239008  box_2           1
12  0.366326  box_3           1
13  0.243075  box_3           1
14  0.217879  box_2           0
15  0.915162  box_3           0
16  0.733101  box_3           0
17  0.352939  box_2           0
18  0.324632  box_3           1
19  0.359596  box_3           0
```

The logic behind this :

I have many boxes in dict format, In each box, there is *`'full_packets'`* and *`'true_packets'`*, *`'true_packets'`* are always same in each box. I've to compare each box's *`'full_packets'`* to *`'true_packets'`* and if *`'full_packets'`* and *`'true_packets'`* value is equal then take that index from
that box's *`'full_network'`* .

Example :

```
network_a = [1,0,0,1]
data_a    = [11,22,33,44]
loss      = 0.2

network_b = [1,1,0,1]
data_b    = [111,222,333,444]
loss      = 0.1

true_values = [1,1,1,1]
```

Now first of all sort the values based on loss then comparing *`network_a`* with true_values :

```
# creating a blank result same len of true values
result = ['blank','blank', 'blank', 'blank']

network_a  == true_values
[1,0,0,1]  == [1,1,1,1]
```

as you can see index `0th`,`4th` are same so I'll take *`0th`* and *`4th`* from `data_a` and store in `result` now updated `result` will be :

```
result = [11, 'blank', 'blank', 44]
```

Now comparing `network_b  == true_values` :

```
network_b  == true_values
[1,1,0,1]  == [1,1,1,1]
```

Here is a contradiction since *`0th`*, *`1th`*, *`4th`* are same and in *`network_a`* also have *`0th`* and *`4th`* are same but I won't change the value in *`result`* of *`0th`* and *`4th`* because I am giving more priority to more loss.  *`network_a`*'s loss is more so I'll keep *`0th`* and *`4th`* from *`network_a`* and *`1st`* from *`network_b`*'s *`data_b`*

so updated `*result*` will be :

```
result = [11, 222, 'blank', 44]
```

Since there is no `*3rd*` index same neither in *`network_a`* nor in *`network_b`* so I'll let it be *`'blank'`* only.

What I've tried :

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd

# sorting based on packet loss
od = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['packet_loss'], reverse=True))

# seprating full packets, full networks and true packets
full_packets = {}
full_network = {}
true_packets = []

for model_name, model_result in od.items():
    full_packets[model_name] = model_result['full_packets']
    full_network[model_name]    = model_result['full_network']
    true_packets.append(model_result['true_packets'])
    
    
# creating blank true packets for filling it later ( after comparison)
final_result = ['blank'] * len(true_packets[0])

# checking if which true_packets are same in each box's full_packets 
for m, n in full_packets.items():
    for k in range(len(n)):
        full_pack = n[k]
        true_pack = true_packets[0][k]
        if full_pack ==  true_pack:
            if final_result[k] == 'blank':
                final_result[k] = m
                

final_packets = ['blank'] * len(true_packets[0])

# Now those packets's index which are same or equal to true packets taking those index from their full_network data
for m in range(len(true_packets[0])):
    
    meta_data   = final_result[m]
    if meta_data in full_network:
        final_packets[m] = full_network[meta_data][m]

combined_data = list(zip(final_packets,final_result,true_packets[0]))
df = pd.DataFrame(combined_data, columns=['packets', 'box', 'true_value'])
```

result is :

```
     packets    box  true_value
0   0.771185  box_1           0
1   0.793482  box_3           1
2   0.309031  box_3           0
3   0.447894  box_3           1
4   0.632156  box_3           0
5   0.274967  box_3           0
6   0.211427  box_3           0
7   0.777920  box_3           1
8   0.672390  box_1           1
9   0.440965  box_3           1
10  0.140608  box_3           0
11  0.239008  box_2           1
12  0.366326  box_3           1
13  0.243075  box_3           1
14  0.217879  box_2           0
15  0.915162  box_3           0
16  0.733101  box_3           0
17  0.352939  box_2           0
18  0.324632  box_3           1
19  0.359596  box_3           0
```

It is working but I am looking for advice on how to improve the performance of this code? What is elegant solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I corrected my answer. Now my solution should do what is requested.

Here a possible solution.

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

size = 20
max_vals = [(-1, "blank", "blank")]*size
od = OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['packet_loss'], reverse=True))

for box in od:
    max_vals = list(map(lambda x, y, z, m: (z,box,x) if x==y and m[0] == -1 else m, 
                          data[box]['full_packets'], 
                          data[box]['true_packets'], 
                          data[box]['full_network'],
                          max_vals))

df = pd.DataFrame(max_vals, columns=['packets', 'box', 'true_value'])
print(df)
```

Result:

```
     packets    box  true_value
0   0.771185  box_1           0
1   0.793482  box_3           1
2   0.309031  box_3           0
3   0.447894  box_3           1
4   0.632156  box_3           0
5   0.274967  box_3           0
6   0.211427  box_3           0
7   0.777920  box_3           1
8   0.672390  box_1           1
9   0.440965  box_3           1
10  0.140608  box_3           0
11  0.239008  box_2           1
12  0.366326  box_3           1
13  0.243075  box_3           1
14  0.217879  box_2           0
15  0.915162  box_3           0
16  0.733101  box_3           0
17  0.352939  box_2           0
18  0.324632  box_3           1
19  0.359596  box_3           0
```

Comment: Total elements are 20 but in your solution, it's 30. The final result will be total of 20 elements.

Comment: The problem is not explained well

I've to compare each box's 'full_packets' to 'true_packets' and if 'full_packets' and 'true_packets' value is equal then take that index from that box's 'full_network' .

Here you do not mention that for each packet you consider the box with the maximum value of 'full_network'

Comment: I am not taking the max value, please read the question again. It depends on max_loss not max value. :)

Comment: @AadityaUra can you confirm that now the solution is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
_DATA = {'box_1': {'total_packets': 20,
  'packet_loss': 0.32,
  'network_loss': 0.11,
  'full_packets': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  'full_network': [0.77118516, 0.15721157, 0.99284172, 0.64352685, 0.43893093,
         0.90650645, 0.31344131, 0.98757972, 0.67239033, 0.45789615,
         0.14901635, 0.86344737, 0.46589434, 0.66976324, 0.19622047,
         0.38090317, 0.76307877, 0.26002821, 0.20494155, 0.84978815],
  'true_packets': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]},
 'box_2': {'total_packets': 20,
  'packet_loss': 0.12,
  'network_loss': 0.11,
  'full_packets': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
  'full_network': [0.05200178, 0.27056008, 0.10674939, 0.78031958, 0.18292721,
         0.52281292, 0.94423851, 0.07988127, 0.6556706 , 0.82108989,
         0.13918205, 0.23900761, 0.45053918, 0.80958751, 0.21787875,
         0.38729694, 0.64058867, 0.35293909, 0.3345066 , 0.52221203],
  'true_packets': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]},
 'box_3': {'total_packets': 20,
  'packet_loss': 0.62,
  'network_loss': 0.11,
  'full_packets': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
  'full_network': [0.65296846, 0.79348183, 0.30903056, 0.44789374, 0.63215569,
         0.2749674 , 0.21142709, 0.77792007, 0.70627136, 0.44096512,
         0.1406084 , 0.92678541, 0.36632565, 0.24307549, 0.22864354,
         0.91516214, 0.7331007 , 0.66654516, 0.32463232, 0.35959552],
  'true_packets': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]}}


def _f(data):
    # Sort boxes by packet loss
    boxes = sorted(data.keys(),
                   key=lambda box_name: data[box_name]['packet_loss'])
    result = None
    for box_name in boxes:
        box_data = data[box_name]
        full_packets = box_data['full_packets']
        true_packets = box_data['true_packets']
        all_packets = box_data['full_network']
        if result is None:
            # Initialize result
            result = [None] * len(true_packets)

        for tp_index in range(len(true_packets)):
            if true_packets[tp_index] != full_packets[tp_index]:
                continue

            result[tp_index] = {
                'packet': all_packets[tp_index],
                'box': box_name,
                'true_value': true_packets[tp_index],
            }
    return result


packets = _f(_DATA)
print('Total packets: {}'.format(len(packets)))
print('')
for packet in packets:
    if packet is None:
        continue

    print(packet['packet'], packet['box'], packet['true_value'])
```

Output:

```
Total packets: 20

0.77118516 box_1 0
0.79348183 box_3 1
0.30903056 box_3 0
0.44789374 box_3 1
0.63215569 box_3 0
0.2749674 box_3 0
0.21142709 box_3 0
0.77792007 box_3 1
0.67239033 box_1 1
0.44096512 box_3 1
0.1406084 box_3 0
0.23900761 box_2 1
0.36632565 box_3 1
0.24307549 box_3 1
0.21787875 box_2 0
0.91516214 box_3 0
0.7331007 box_3 0
0.35293909 box_2 0
0.32463232 box_3 1
0.35959552 box_3 0
```